# How to generate sorbet.rbi files for new added Models in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sorbet

I've created a new model Attachment.rb and run

> srb tc

But sorbet is throwing error because the Method doesn't exist for the Attachment model https://srb.help/7003

I tried running **srb rbi update** but turns out it re-runs my whole application.

I've searched and read through all the docs but I couldn't find anything on how to generate the RBI files just for the model. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `zsh` try escaping the `[` `]` :

`bundle exec rake rails_rbi:models\[Attachment\]`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [sorbet-rails](https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/sorbet-rails/)? You can run `bundle exec rake rails_rbi:models[Attachment]` to regenerate RBI for just that model.

Comment: I'm getting this error:

zsh: no matches found: rails_rbi:models[Attachment]

Comment: when using [] inside a rake task, I have to put single quotes around it:

`bundle exec rake 'rails_rbi:models[Attachment]'`